# Python - Nicest way to join two lists of strings and sort its elements

Tags: python

Suppose I have two lists of strings:

```
 x=['a','b'] and b=['c','d']
```

and the end result that I need is:

```
 v=['ac','ad','bc','bd']
```

The important part is that I want the letters of the elements of the list to be sorted. Here they are by contruction, but in my actual problem this is not so. So if I had 'ba', in the list v we should sort it an add 'ab'.

So I can iterate through x, and create a list using

```
 c = ' , '.join('%s%s' % t for t in zip(a, b))
```

but this does not work because even if I manage to make it sorted, then the end result will be a list of 1 element ['ac ,ad,bc,bd'].

In reality what I would love to see if there is any pythonic way of doing it using itertools, or something like

```
 ' ''.join('sorted(%s%s)' % t for t in zip(a, b))
```

Thank you!

Note: Thank you all for the replies, but maybe I expressed myself incorrectly...

So if we try with the inputs:

```
 a=['ax','ay','az']
 b=['x','y','z']
```

So the joint should be:

```
 v=['axx', 'axy', 'axz', 'ayx', 'ayy', 'ayz', 'azx', 'azy', 'azz'] but sorting it....
 v=['axx', 'axy', 'axz', 'axy', 'ayy', 'ayz', 'axz', 'ayz', 'azz']
```

which is the final result I'm looking.

Thanks

Comment: your end result isn't sorted - 'ayy' is not alphabetically before `axz', but you seem to want them to be. I think you need to clearly explain what your sorting rules are.

Comment: each of the entry strings in the list should be sorted. I am not sure if he is interested in the list being sorted.

Comment: I need each entry in the list to be sorted alphabetically. This is because then each entry in this list is going to be the key of a Networkx graph, so sorting will prevent me from adding more nodes when its actually the same one.

Comment: To avoid duplication you would use a `set()` or `frozenset()`. It can only contain elements not or once.

Comment: Please clarify.  Do you really want duplicated items in the list like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
sorted([''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(list1, list2)])
```

If also you want each item to be sorted internally, you can do this:

```
sorted([''.join(sorted(x)) for x in itertools.product(list1, list2)])
```

However, as in your example that you added to your question, this will result in duplicates if there are multiple combinations of the input lists that contain the same set of characters.

Comment: Sorry! I thought this worked but look, let: a=['ax','ay','az'], b=['x','y','z']. The output of your code is ['axx', 'axy', 'axz', 'ayx', 'ayy', 'ayz', 'azx', 'azy', 'azz']. But see we have ayx,azx,azy, so the sorting is not quite right...

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted(i + j for i in x for j in y)
```

Comment: `(i + j for i in sorted(x) for j in sorted(y))` also works and may be faster.

Comment: I tried it but I get the same as the other replies. The final list, if you try it with a general a b is not sorted. I updated the question and added an example, maybe I expressed myself wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
[''.join(sorted(i + j)) for i in a for j in b]
```

Output:

```
['axx', 'axy', 'axz', 'axy', 'ayy', 'ayz', 'axz', 'ayz', 'azz']
```

Comment: No need for `list`, but apart from that, nice, and this indeed seems to be what OP wanted. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(lambda s: ''.join(sorted(s)), sorted(i + j for i in a for j in b)))
```

or

```
sorted(''.join(sorted(i + j)) for i in a for j in b)
```

Comment: This doesn't really work for a general a and b. I tried it but the final list is not sorted. I added the example because maybe I expressed myself incorrectly. Thanks!